# Is there a general formula for SVD of inverse matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

Suppose $A$ is a square invertible matrix and let $A=USV^{*}$ be a SVD of $A$.

(Note that $U,V$ are unitary and $S$ is diagonal with descending entries on diagonal)

At first, I thought SVD of $A^{-1} = VS^{-1}U^{*}$, but it was wrong since diagonal entries of $S^{-1}$ is not descending order.

I think there is no general formula for SVD of $A^{-1}$, am I right?

Or is there any idea that I don't know?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The descending entries on the diagonal isn't really crucial. If you insist you can reorder them via a permutation matrix.

Comment: Of course you also need to modify $V$ and $U$. Explicitly let $P$ be the permutation matrix corresponding to the "reverse" permutation which swaps $1$ and $n$, $2$ and $n-1$, etc. Then the SVD of $A^{-1}$ is $(VP) (PS^{-1}P)(PU^{\ast})$. $P$ has the effect of reordering the diagonal entries in the necessary way while also applying a matching permutation to the left and right singular vectors.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So it is valid since $P$ is an orthogonal matrix, and then each $VP, PU^{*} $ are unitary and  $PS^{-1}P$ diagonal with descending entries, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You are just reversing the order of the singular values and then making sure the correct left and right singular vectors are still paired up with them, nothing complicated is going on here.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan But one thing, since SVD is unique, we can determine what you said is "the" SVD of $A^{-1}$, right? if not, maybe there could be many SVD, so...

Comment: The SVD in this matrix form is not totally unique. Even in the best case when all the singular values are distinct there is still a sign ambiguity in the left and right singular vectors (over $\mathbb{R}$, and over $\mathbb{C}$ there is a phase ambiguity). If some of the singular values have multiplicities then there are uncountably many different SVDs.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Okay, but one thing, $P^2 \neq I$, so I think ($VP^T$) is right, since a permutation matrix is orthogonal.

Comment: No, $P^2 = I$, it's just a bunch of transpositions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149053/discussion-between-jaemto-and-qiaochu-yuan).